# Failing to install MSI using ps1 script on remote using another PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, windows-server-2008, remote-server

I am trying to install software (MSI) on remote server using a PowerShell script. The script was able to download the MSI file from the Internet, but fails to install the MSI.

When the remote script is executed directly by logging in to remote server it works fine and installs the MSI.

Script to be executed on remote servers (`remote.ps1`):

```
$base_url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/python-2.7.13.amd64.msi"
$python_filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($base_url)
$output_filepath = "D:\Temp\$python_filename"

Remove-Item -Path "C:\python27" -Force -Verbose
$installation_path = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\python27"

$get_pip_url = "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"
$pip_name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($get_pip_url)
$get_pip_path = "D:\Temp\$pip_name"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest $base_url -OutFile "D:\Temp\$python_filename"
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/qn /i $output_filepath InstallAllUsers=1 TargetDir=$installation_path" -Wait
```

Script to be executed on the local computer (`local.ps1`):

```
$username = "user1"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

$script = {
    Param(
        [String]$Application,
        [String]$Environment,
        [String]$Region,
        [String]$Service,
        [String]$Node_Number,
        [String]$proxy_sec_method,
        [String]$proxy_url
    )

    $pyinstall = D:\Temp\remote.ps1
    $pyinstall
}
Copy-Item -Path "\\localServerName\d$\Monitoring\*" -Destination "\\remoteServerName\d$\Temp" -Force -Recurse
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName remoteServerName -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $Application, $Environment, $Region, $Service, $Node_Number, $proxy_sec_method, $proxy_url -Verbose
```

In the local script I have tried changing the code lines `$pyinstall = D:\Temp\remote.ps1` to `$pyinstall = Invoke-Expression -Command 'D:\Temp\pythoninstallation.ps1'` But was unable get the MSI installed.

Comment: are you getting any error messages? Does 'user1' have permissions on the remote server to install things? What is the meaning of all these parameters in the scriptblock? (none of them seems to be used in the remote.ps1)

Comment: 1. I did get any error messages.
2. User1 has been added to adminusers on remote server.
3. parameters mentioned in the remote.ps1 are used in the next steps which i have not copied here. 
4. By changing the last 2lines in local.ps1 to below
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteServerName -Credential $cred -FilePath 'D:\Temp\remote.ps1' -Verbose` i did not have any luck

Comment: Use the call operator instead of `Start-Process`, and have `msiexec` create a log file, so you can inspect what happened: `& msiexec.exe /qn /i $output_filepath 'InstallAllUsers=1' "TargetDir=$installation_path" /l*v C:\install.log`

Comment: There's a spurious closing curly bracket in your `local.ps1`. Is that the actual code you were trying to run? Because it *should* have given you a syntax error. Does the file `D:\Temp\remote.ps1` exist on the remote host?

Comment: Since u said that the file is getting downloaded, it is safe to say that `remote.ps1` is getting invoked properly. That leaves the installation part. Instead of `Start-process` can you try the traditional method `cmd /c "msiexec.exe /qn /i $output_filepath InstallAllUsers=1 TargetDir=$installation_path"`. I didn't test the code but I vaguely remember that's how I used it.